# django ajax return template as data

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-templates

How do you when making an ajax request to a view return the template data to the jquery call.

As an example, i am making an ajax call this way.

```
<script>
  function getProfile(username) {
     $.getJSON("/profiles/"+username, { username:{{ username }}}, function(json){
                            alert("Was successful?: " + json['success']);
                        });
                    }
   function addClickHandlers() {
           $(".person-name").click( function()
                getProfile(result.user.username) });
                    }
                    $(document).ready(addClickHandlers);
  </script>
```

My django view

```
def profiles_view(request, username):
#    if username:
#        selected_user = User.objects.get(username = username)
    results = {'success':False}
    if request.method == u'GET':
        GET = request.GET
        if GET.has_key(u'username'):
            results = {'success':True}
    json = simplejson.dumps(results)

    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

Can i pass my template view `profiles_view.html` to the HttpResponse? i am not sure where my template comes in?

Comment: You can take a look at this question, if you find it useful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104690/django-how-to-return-model-formset-in-ajax-and-use-in-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need both HTML view and JSON view, you may need two responses. First is from `TemplateResponse`, second one is from `HttpResponse`. Two requests seem inefficient, but the first request is once for all, afterwards you only need JSON response by use of AJAX request.

You can return a template by:

```
 return TemplateResponse(request, "profiles_view.html", results)
```

Comment: I only need a TemplateResponse, the only reason i am making an ajax request is to display html in specific div. any examples on TemplateResponse?

Comment: I added a snippet in my answer. If you only need one ajax request, you can consider merging two requests in one template view, otherwise you'd better separate them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a template if you are just going to pass data through ajax.

Comment: i want to load the template in a specific div and i am making the ajax request in the same page.