# ManyToManyFields as IntegerFields in Django admin interface

Tags: django, django-forms, manytomanyfield, django-widget

Assuming I have :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    [...]

class Basket(models.Model):
    content = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through="ProductQuantity")

class ProductQuantity(models.Model):
    basket = models.ForeignKey(Basket)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

How could I render a `ModelForm` for the `Basket` Model with a field for each `ProductQuantity` of a `Basket`, just to be able to modify its `quantity` attribute?

Is there a widget I could use for this?

If I was able to do such thing with such a ModelForm, could I use this `ModelForm` in an `admin.ModelAdmin` as an alternative `form` attribute to have the same behaviour in the admin interface?

## Edit :

@MuhammadTahir marked this post as possible duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021242/accessing-many-to-many-through-relation-fields-in-formsets).

It indeed helped me to understand better, but I'm still stuck : I can't render the fields I want to render.

Here is my code so far :

**models.py**

Same as above.

**forms.py**

```
ProductQuantityFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Product,
                                               basket.content.through,
                                               fields=("quantity",))
```

**admin.py**

```
class ProductQuantityInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ProductQuantity
    formset = ProductQuantityFormSet()

class BasketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inline = [ProductQuantityInline,]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing Many to Many "through" relation fields in Formsets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021242/accessing-many-to-many-through-relation-fields-in-formsets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on IRC found the problem :

`inline` ≠ `inlines` in the `admin.ModelAdmin`. And I don't even need the `inlineformset_factory()`.

So here is the final code :

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    [...]

class Basket(models.Model):
    content = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through="ProductQuantity")

class ProductQuantity(models.Model):
    basket = models.ForeignKey(Basket)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**admin.py**

```
class ProductQuantityInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ProductQuantity
    fields = ["quantity",]

class BasketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProductQuantityInline,]
```

I hope this could help somebody else. :)