# many to many relationship between multiple tables using django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have two tables `borrower` and `lender`. A borrower can request many lenders and lenders also can get multiple requests from borrowers.

So I want to give many to many relation between two of this. Something like:

```
class borrower(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # . . . other fields

class lender(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # . . . other fields
```

Now in the `loanrequest` table I want to define many to many relation between these two tables. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding from the little information that you have provided, you may try doing this:

```
Class Borrower(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  lender = models.ManyToManyField(to='Lender', related_name='borrow', through='LoanRequest')

class LoanRequest(models.Model):
  borrower = models.ForeignKey(to='Borrower', related_name='loan_borrower')
  lender = models.ForeignKey(to='Lender', related_name='loan_lender')
```

Also, you may add other fields in LoanRequest model as per your need (for ex- final_rate_of_interest - this ofcourse is an example, you may change as per your requirement).

Anyways, you might giving [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), [this](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/describing-relationships-djangos-manytomany-through/) (for knowing 'through' tables),and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368442/how-do-i-access-the-properties-of-a-many-to-many-through-table-from-a-django-t) a read.