# Django REST field level costume permissions in a ViewSet

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'd like to validate whether users have permission to update a "shared_with" field , right now I'm doing it with a direct call to .has_perm, but this seems to not scalable, anyone know what's the best practice in this case?

views.py:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    @staticmethod
    def _check_sharing_permission(request: Request):
        if request.data.get('shared_with') and not 
        request.user.has_perm(CAN_SHARE_PERMISSION_CODENAME):
            raise PermissionDenied('you shall not pass!')

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self._check_sharing_permission(request)
        return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Found the answer in this thread, no need to use has_perm the intermidiet table can be referenced:

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:
[How do I access the properties of a many-to-many "through" table from a django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368442/how-do-i-access-the-properties-of-a-many-to-many-through-table-from-a-django-t)

No need to use has_perm
The intermediate table can be referenced in such cases